# GET method not working after passportjs integration

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, rest, passport.js

I have the following REST method in route.js.

```
app.get('/api/todos', isAuthenticated, function(req, res) {
    DB.TodoTable.find()
    .exec(function(err, todos) {
        res.json(todos, function(err){
            if (err) console.log(err);
        });     // return all todos in JSON format

        console.dir(res);
    });
});
```

While debugging this I found that 'res' object's 'statusCode' field hold the data. This is definitely wrong. And may be because of this its not getting received at angular side.
eg.

```
{
    ...
    statusCode:
     [ { index: Mon Jan 19 2015 09:33:54 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time),
         text: 'hello',
         _id: 23ffs2sdfsdd64c0834534,
         __v: 0 } ] 
}
```

In controller.js I have another method:

```
Todos.get()
    .success(function(data) {
        console.info("Data received from server:");
        console.dir(data);
    });
```

Here I get 'data' as "". This used to work before passportjs integration.

Is this really cause of passportjs. If not, how could i get this working.

Comment: No, it's not because of passport. Do you handle `statusCode` in e.g. some middleware like `isAuthenticated`?

Comment: @vesse Nope i havent used it anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working after removing the callback from 'res.json' method call.

The callback is causing the unexpected behaviour in this case. Not sure exactly whats the reason behind this.

But the following works:

```
app.get('/api/todos', isAuthenticated, function(req, res) {
    DB.TodoTable.find()
    .exec(function(err, todos) {
        res.json(todos);     // return all todos in JSON format

        console.dir(res);
    });
});
```

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't even look at that part. Yeah, you cannot give a callback to `res.json`. It does still [support two arguments](https://github.com/strongloop/express/blob/9434ad39e114ea810859cd9c6fef624d4acfbe18/lib/response.js#L208-L236) since in previous versions you could give `statusCode` to it as well, ie. `res.json(400, {status: "error"});`

Comment: No issues. I thought I will try it once more. And it worked. Thanks a lot )